# Handling Custom Login with Extra Callback

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am building a OAuth2 provider server with Spring Security 5 and Spring Boot 2.1.

In my case, my server has to communicate with some external server to authenticate the user. This external server is living in dinosaurs age hence using no common authentication mechanisms like OAuth. So I have to hijack login request, redirect to dinosaur server, manually handle that authentication (which includes callbacks, unfortunately), then return to spring security to approve login request and make sure user gets an access token.

Hijacking the login request as follows:

```
@Override
  protected void configure ( HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception {
    http
        .requestMatchers()
        .antMatchers( "/login", "/oauth/authorize", "/manuallogin" )
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage( "/manuallogin" )
        .permitAll()
        .and().csrf().disable();
  }
```

```
@RestController
public class MainLoginController {

  @RequestMapping("/manuallogin")
  ResponseEntity<Object> interceptLoginRequest ( ){
    return ResponseEntity.status( HttpStatus.FOUND )
                         .location( URI.create( dinosaurServer.getLoginUrl() ) )
                         .build();
  }

  @RequestMapping("/handshakeWithDinosaur")
  @Override
  public ResponseEntity<Object> handshakeWithDinosaur ( String dinosaursToken ) {

    Principal principal = getUserPrincipalFromDinosaur();

    // somehow continue login, here is the problem
  }
```

as you see, I need to accept another callback so I am losing the original login request, I can not send a response to that.

I came up with following solution, cutting short by calling the callback URL of OAuth2 client.

```
    Principal principal = getUserPrincipalFromDinosaur();
    Credential credential = new Credential();
    credential.setUsername( "john"  );
    credential.setPassword( "123" );


    PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken preAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken( principal, credential);
    preAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken.setAuthenticated( true );

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication( preAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken);



    return ResponseEntity.status( HttpStatus.FOUND )
                         .location( URI.create( String.format( oauth2client.getCallbackUrl(), dinosaursToken ) ))
                         .build();
```

yet, this does not work as spring doesn't accept the authenticaton.

I have to somehow continue to the original login request and authenticate the user. Thank you very much even if you read all this :)

Comment: I don't know Spring. _I need to accept another callback so I am losing the original login request_ Some suggestions: Can you use a cache like SQL with sessionId ? Can you return a base64(xxx) and save to `sessionStorage` on web browser ?

Comment: my solution is based on sessions as you said, but Spring manages that for me instead of sql. posting now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any desperate soul that encounters this problem, here is the solution :

```
@RestController
public class MainLoginController {

  @RequestMapping("/manuallogin")
  ResponseEntity<Object> interceptLoginRequest ( ){
    ServletRequestAttributes requestAttributes = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
    DefaultSavedRequest springSecuritySavedRequest = (DefaultSavedRequest) requestAttributes.getRequest()
                                                                                            .getSession()
                                                                                            .getAttribute( "SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST" );
    queryString = springSecuritySavedRequest.getQueryString();
    request.getSession().setAttribute( "queryString", queryString );

    return ResponseEntity.status( HttpStatus.FOUND )
                         .location( URI.create( dinosaurServer.getLoginUrl() ) )
                         .build();
  }

  @RequestMapping("/handshakeWithDinosaur")
  public ResponseEntity<Object> handshakeWithDinosaur ( String dinosaursToken ) {


    Authentication authentication = this.authenticationManager.authenticate(
        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
            dino.getUser(), dino.getPass()
        )
    );
    SecurityContext sc = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    sc.setAuthentication( authentication );
    request.getSession().setAttribute( SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY, sc );


    String queryString = String.valueOf( request.getSession().getAttribute( "queryString" ) );

    return ResponseEntity.status( HttpStatus.FOUND )
                         .location( URI.create( String.format( "%s?%s",SPRING_AUTH_ENDPOINT, queryString ) ) )
                         .build();
  }
```

```
@Component
public class AuthProviderForDinosaur implements AuthenticationProvider {


  @Override
  public Authentication authenticate ( Authentication authentication ) throws AuthenticationException {
    List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<>();
    grantedAuths.add( new SimpleGrantedAuthority( "ROLE_USER" ) );
    return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken( authentication.getName(), authentication.getCredentials(), grantedAuths );
  }

  @Override
  public boolean supports ( Class<? extends Object> authentication ) {
    return ( UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom( authentication ) );
  }
}
```

Basically, I enabled sessions and let Spring hold the request for me in a session while the server talks to dinosaur server and completes the handshake. After completion, asks Spring for previous request's parameters to continue authorization though Spring Security.